# How can I save my Xamarin Forms MainPage.xaml as PDF using a button?

Tags: c#, xamarin, pdf, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

On the front screen of the mobile app I have entries that I filled with info, now I want to make a button that saves the page as PDF with all the info I entered inside the entries. Help?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Nuget package called **PdfSharp.Xamarin.Forms** that takes a view and turns it into a pdf. Library link:
https://github.com/akgulebubekir/PDFSharp.Xamarin.Forms

You have to init it fro each platform seperately:
**PdfSharp.Xamarin.Forms.{Platform}.Platform.Init()**

Generate pdf :
**var pdf = PDFManager.GeneratePDFFromView(yourView)**

Save pdf:
**DependencyService.Get().Save(pdf, "pdfName.pdf")**

Answer (score 1):

There is a library to save and open PDF files in xamarin that might come in handy to you:

https://github.com/officialdoniald/Xamarin.Forms.Save.Open.PDF

Gerald Verslius has a video on it as well which can be found here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqetV1Lh-9c&ab_channel=GeraldVersluis

Sample: https://github.com/officialdoniald/Xamarin.Forms.Save.Open.PDF/tree/master/Xamarin.Forms.Save.Open.PDF

Comment: I'm only meant to use these right? PdfSharp.Xamarin.Sample and PdfSharp.Xamarin.Sample.Android

Comment: I think you commented on the wrong answer but yes, that's what you are meant to use!